# NPM running very slow on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, npm

I have a pretty simple react application that I created with Create-React-App. When I run `npm start`, it executes `react-scripts start` as expected. However, I have to wait nearly 10 minutes for the dev server to start. `npm run build` also takes nearly 10 minutes. Even simply running `npm -version` takes 10-20 seconds to get output.

I have the latest version of npm installed on my machine (currently 7.21.1).

I am on Windows 10 (64 bit) running commands in powershell (although, running them in git bash does not change anything). I have 32GB of RAM and am not running many other programs. I am unsure what additional information would be helpful, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how is npm installed ? what's the version? what are the install locations?

Comment: @YashKumarVerma npm is installed globally (This PC > OS(C:) > Program Files > nodejs > node_modules > npm). NPM v17.21.1, Node v14.17.3.

Answer (score -3):

Try Yarn. I think yarn is more smoother than npm.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: *"Pick a different problem"* is not a solution.